# Visual Studio Code pixels turn white

Tags: visual-studio-code

What can i do to fix this problem? Im on an Asus laptop, 1950 x 1080 and 144 hz, 125% scaling
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NwRM.png)

Comment: Try to reduce monitor Hz refreshing. I don't think is the monitor scaling.

Comment: I tried, didnt help

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: Idk if i did it right, but it didnt help either :(

Comment: Is it 125% Windows scaling?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+"+" and Ctrl+"-" in VS Code?

Comment: Try to update graphical driver. I have searched in internet and other people are experiencing this glitch (https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/xtnhrs/help_with_screen_glitch_in_visual_studio/).